# LDAP Authentication using CAS

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, cas

I'm trying to get LDAP to work via CAS 4.0.

When I log in, I get the following in my catalina.out log:

```
2018-07-03 13:25:01,426 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <AcceptUsersAuthenticationHandler failed authenticating administrator+password>
2018-07-03 13:25:01,448 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: supplied credentials: [administrator+password]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Tue Jul 03 13:25:01 UTC 2018
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 10.1.1.8
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 10.1.1.69
=============================================================


2018-07-03 13:25:01,450 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: 1 errors, 0 successes
ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_NOT_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Tue Jul 03 13:25:01 UTC 2018
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 10.1.1.8
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 10.1.1.69
=============================================================
```

My deployerConfigContext.xml is at https://pastebin.com/mR1NvNWx

My cas.properties is at https://pastebin.com/YSyUcVtL

I've tried to set it up using instructions at https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.0.x/installation/LDAP-Authentication.html

As far as I can tell, i've followed the instructions correctly. At this point, I'm not sure where I should be looking, as the log isn't really descriptive as to the cause of the problem(it looks like bad username/password but, they're definitely correct). I also note that the log doesn't seem to mention ldap at all:
https://pastebin.com/A0U16YqG

Does anyone have any ideas, or able to point me in the right direction?